# web.py form validation formatting

Tags: web.py

I'm following a web.py tutorial that is using the web.py `form` module.  Basically, this little app creates a form consisting of a text box, does some validation to make sure it's a number and that it's greater than 10, and decides if that number was odd or even.  I'll post the code before the question as it'll be easier to understand.

code.py

```
import web
from web import form

urls = (
  '/', 'hello')

number_form = form.Form( 
    form.Textbox('number',
             form.notnull,
             form.regexp('^-?\d+$', 'Not a number.'),
             form.Validator('Not greater than 10.', lambda x: int(x)>10),
             description='Enter a number greater than 10:'
             ))

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=True)

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        my_form = number_form()
        return render.hello(my_form)

    def POST(self): 
        my_form = number_form() 
        if not my_form.validates(): 
            return render.hello(my_form)
        else:
            number = my_form['number'].value
            if int(number) % 2:
                return "Your number %s is odd." % number
        else:
            return "Your number %s is even." % number

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

hello.html

```
$def with (form)
<form name="test" method="POST"> 
$if not form.valid: <p><b>Sorry, your input was invalid.</b></p> 
$:form.render()
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Now, my question is about the validators defined when I create `number_form`.  If I were to change the line:

```
form.regexp('^-?\d+$', 'Not a number.'),
```

to something like:

```
form.regexp('^-?\d+$', 'Not          a           number.'),
```

the output doesn't change! It still just says `Not a number.` if it fails that validation.  But if I change it to something like:

```
form.regexp('^-?\d+$', 'NOT A NUMBER.'),
```

it displays `NOT A NUMBER.`, so I know it is interpreting that line, and that my changes actually took.

I've tried a few different strings, and it seems like it is truncating spaces or something; everything I've changed it to works fine, except adding things like spaces, newlines, tabs, etc.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats how browser displays your page, it considers any whitespace as a one space, unless you change [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) in css to `pre`.